# jacoco is not picking up the report path correctly

Tags: spring, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

Our report generation was working fine before we made some changes. Now, I am not at all able to make it work, I have tried all solutions which I can find.

This is our older code :

```
           <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>none</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now, we have changed it to below code :

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>none</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

As you can see, we have added some configuration, and as per my extensive search for issues, the only hint which I got is to update the argline to below code

```
<argLine>${argLine} -Xmx1024m</argLine>
```

but now I get the below error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app2/azdosagents/agent3/_work/21029/s/CCReport43F6D5EF/jacoco.exec (No such file or directory)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_035b120.output.FileOutput.openFile(FileOutput.java:67)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_035b120.output.FileOutput.writeExecutionData(FileOutput.java:53)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_035b120.Agent.shutdown(Agent.java:137)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_035b120.Agent$1.run(Agent.java:54)
```

Now, what I see is previously jacoco was picking up the directories correctly, It was storing the jacoco in target/jacoco.exec. but now it picks up a location which doesnot even exists.

I have spend a day in this, but still no luck. any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: it doesn't work even if you rollback to older code?

Comment: it works but then we have made other changes as well which we cant skip like changed parent pom and resolved other issue with the plugin, which goes away with the argument passed.

Comment: does it means the configuration section is the minimal changes from older code causing the error?

Comment: yes, along with the jacoco plugin version change which I dont have any control as its coming from parent file

Comment: `jacoco plugin version change` that may be the root cause, what is the version after change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using the parent jacoco version and using the default arguments.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>none</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```